# Using the jQuery selectors recursively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following JavaScript:

```
function checkAvailability(o) {
    o = $(o);
    var p = $(o[0].parentNode);

    if (!o.val()) {
        return;
    }

    p.children('name=ajaxState').attr('src', '/images/busy.gif');
```

which is attempting to leverage the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <image name="ajaxState"
         src="/images/blank1616.png"
         style="float: right; width: 24px; height: 24px; margin-right: 1em;" />
  <input name="displayname" id="displayname" type="text"
         placeholder="Display Name"
         check-length min="1" max="45"
         onblur="checkAvailability(this);" />
</div>
```

where `o` is a wrapped `input` element, and `p` is a wrapped `div` element. What I want to do is get at the `image` element named `ajaxState` inside the `div` element, but that JavaScript throws:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: name=ajaxState

How can I use the same selector syntax to get at child elements here?

Comment: Do you really mean `<image>` and not `<img>`?

Comment: @harpo, fantastic catch. It's insane how that actually renders in the browser, really!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name=ajaxState` is the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), it should be enclosed within `[]`

```
p.children('[name=ajaxState]').attr('src', '/images/busy.gif');
```

It can be simplified a little to

```
function checkAvailability(o) {
    o = $(o);

    if (!o.val()) {
        return;
    }

    var p = o.parent()
    p.children('[name=ajaxState]').attr('src', '/images/busy.gif');
```